# How to add an ID to every div element created inside a .forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an ID for every booksDisplay div because I want bookOne, bookTwo, bookThree and bookFour to have their own containers. Right now, textNode runs through every div and I want for every div to be seperate. I could have created divs inside HTML but I want to do it dynamically inside javascript.

```js
const booksContainer = document.querySelector('.booksContainer');


const book = {
  title: '',
  author: '',
  pages: '',
  imageUrl: '',
}


const bookOne = {
  imageUrl: '',
  title: 'Title:' + ' ' + 'Armageddon: The Battle for Germany, 1944-1945',
  author: 'Author:' + ' ' + 'Max Hastings',
  pages: 'Pages:' + ' ' + '672'
}
    

const bookTwo = {
  imageUrl: '',
  title: '',
  author: '',
  pages: ''
}


const bookThree = {
  imageUrl: '',
  title: '',
  author: '',
  pages: ''
}


const bookFour = {
  imageUrl: '',
  title: '',
  author: '',
  pages: ''
}
    
let myLibrary = [bookOne, bookTwo, bookThree, bookFour]


myLibrary.forEach((book, index) => {
  let booksDisplay = document.createElement('div')
  booksDisplay.setAttribute('class', 'booksDisplay')
  let booksDisplayText = document.createTextNode(`${bookOne.title}: ${bookOne.author}: ${bookOne.pages}`);
  booksDisplay.appendChild(booksDisplayText)
  booksContainer.appendChild(booksDisplay)

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myLibrary">
   <div class="booksContainer">
     
   </div>
    </div>

    
    <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried something like myLibrary[0].setAttribute('id' 'randomtext'), tried booksDisplay[0].setAttribute('id', 'booksDisplayOne') and that's about it or do I have to create another loop inside a .forEach loop to create an id for every container?

Comment: _"because I want bookOne, bookTwo, bookThree and bookFour to have their own containers"_ - but they already do? And what does an ID have to do with this in the first place?

Comment: You were confusing how [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) work with how [DOM Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) work. See links for their documentation.

Comment: Because I want different content in each container, that's why I want add IDs to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want the id on the html tag? Why not use the loop you already have and use the index as the id?
Also, no need to create a variable for each book, just put them directly in an array:

```js
const booksContainer = document.getElementById('booksContainer');

const myLibrary = [
  {
    imageUrl: '',
    title: 'Title:' + ' ' + 'Armageddon: The Battle for Germany, 1944-1945',
    author: 'Author:' + ' ' + 'Max Hastings',
    pages: 'Pages:' + ' ' + '672'
  },
  {
    imageUrl: '',
    title: 'book 2',
    author: '',
    pages: ''
  },
  {
    imageUrl: '',
    title: 'book 3',
    author: '',
    pages: ''
  },
  {
    imageUrl: '',
    title: 'book 4',
    author: '',
    pages: ''
  }
];

myLibrary.forEach((book, index) => {
  let booksDisplay = document.createElement('div');
  booksDisplay.setAttribute('class', 'booksDisplay')
  booksDisplay.setAttribute('id', `booksDisplay${index + 1}`);

  let booksDisplayText = document.createTextNode(`${book.title}: ${book.author}: ${book.pages}`);
  booksDisplay.appendChild(booksDisplayText);
  booksContainer.appendChild(booksDisplay);
});
```

Comment: Tried to do this but my it seems that my syntax was off. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create `var counter = 0;` outside of your `forEach`.

Then, you have to add only one line of code - `console.log(booksDisplay.id = 'customId' + (++counter))`.

**Note:** `console.log` is there just for clarification.

```js
const booksContainer = document.querySelector('.booksContainer');


const book = {
  title: '',
  author: '',
  pages: '',
  imageUrl: '',
}


const bookOne = {
  imageUrl: '',
  title: 'Title:' + ' ' + 'Armageddon: The Battle for Germany, 1944-1945',
  author: 'Author:' + ' ' + 'Max Hastings',
  pages: 'Pages:' + ' ' + '672'
}

const bookTwo = {
  imageUrl: '',
  title: '',
  author: '',
  pages: ''
}


const bookThree = {
  imageUrl: '',
  title: '',
  author: '',
  pages: ''
}


const bookFour = {
  imageUrl: '',
  title: '',
  author: '',
  pages: ''
}
    
let myLibrary = [bookOne, bookTwo, bookThree, bookFour]

var counter = 0;
myLibrary.forEach((book, index) => {
  let booksDisplay = document.createElement("div")
  booksDisplay.setAttribute('class', 'booksDisplay')
  console.log(booksDisplay.id = 'customId' + (++counter))
  let booksDisplayText = document.createTextNode(`${bookOne.title}: ${bookOne.author}: ${bookOne.pages}`);
  booksDisplay.appendChild(booksDisplayText)
  booksContainer.appendChild(booksDisplay)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myLibrary">
   <div class="booksContainer">
     
   </div>
    </div>

    
    <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```